# C++: #including <thread> redefines winsock function bind(...)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, bind, winsock

Beginning of my CPP file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#define WIN32_MEAN_AND_LEAN
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

(straight out of madwizard.org winsock tutorial). Everything works fine but now whenever i just add `#include <thread>` (anywhere before/after other includes) the following doesnt compile:

```
if (bind(hSocket, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&sockAddr), sizeof(sockAddr)) != 0 )
{
    throw ROTException("could not bind socket.");
}
```

The beginning of error is:

```
error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::_Bind<_Forced,_Ret,_Fun,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t,_V5_t,<unnamed-symbol>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Forced=false,
1>              _Ret=void,
1>              _Fun=SOCKET &,
1>              _V0_t=sockaddr *,
1>              _V1_t=unsigned int,
1>              _V2_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V3_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V4_t=std::_Nil,
1>              _V5_t=std::_Nil,
1>              <unnamed-symbol>=std::_Nil
1>          ]
1>          c:\home\vs\vc\include\exception(522): could be 'bool std::operator !=(const std::exception_ptr &,const std::exception_ptr &)'
```

So its like bind changed type from int to void. If i just write

```
bind(hSocket, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&sockAddr), sizeof(sockAddr));
```

It will compile, but it will not work. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Technically, `std::bind` is in `<functional>`.

Comment: use ::bind() instead of bind()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Short answer

Don't use `using namespace std;`.

## Slightly longer answer

There's `std::bind` in C++11. `using namespace std;` will introduce this version of `bind` to the global namespace, which can lead to problems. You can use `::bind` for your original WinSock bind, but better stay safe and don't use a whole namespace.

Why does this happen if you include `<thread>`? Because `std::thread` might use `std::bind` internally, for which it includes `<functional>` where `std::bind` is declared.